# Change columns format when reading in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, format, missing-data

I have this csv file (called `df.csv`):

[image]

I read it in using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')
```

and I print it out using this code:

```
print(df)
```

and the output of the print looks like this:

```
  employment_type    ltv
0                       
1                       
2        Salaried  77.13
3        Salaried   77.4
4        Salaried  76.42
5        Salaried  71.89
```

As you can see, the first two records are empty.
I check the dataframe info with this code:

```
print(df.info())
```

and the output looks like this:

```
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------           --------------  ----- 
 0   employment_type  6 non-null      object
 1   ltv              6 non-null      object
```

Now, I would expect that:

- `employment_type` would have been read in as object (and that meets my expectations)
- `ltv` would have been read in as float

I guess that the reason why both fields have been read in as objects is because of the first empty record, correct?

Whilst I am happy for `employment_type` to be read in as an object, how can I read in the `ltv` field as numeric?
I don't want to modify the format after I have read the file in. I need to find a way to automatically assign the correct format whilst reading in the file: I will have to read in some similar files with hundreds of columns and I can't manually assign the correct format to each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I guess that the reason why both fields have been read in as objects is because of the first empty record, correct?*
Yes, pandas is pretty good at infering data types, and an empty cell can't be an int or a float.
To fix your issue, just remove these empty rows (with dropna) and you can then write

```
df['ltv']=df['ltv'].astype(float)
```